# Integral of a complex dot/inner product

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, inner-products

How to prove that of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}<z,e^{it}>_+dt = \frac{1}{\pi}|z|$ where $x_+:= \left\{\begin{matrix}
x, x\geq 0 & \\ 
0, x<0 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: use that $<z,e^{it}>=|z|(\cos (t-\theta))$ for $\cos \theta =\frac{x}{|z|}, z=x+iy$ and then that the integral of $\cos(t-\theta)_+$ on a full period is just $2$ - note that here we need a $1/(2\pi)$ factor somewhere, either in the defintion of the inner product or in the integral to get the $1/\pi$

Comment: @Conrad Nice hint.

Comment: @Conrad, the original formula is a sum and to be precise: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{n} <z_k, e^{it}>_{+},dt $

Comment: What is then the exact statement?

Comment: @Conrad, Thanks for your tip. It is one of my homework problems, I almost finished it. To give you context, we have to compute this sum/integral, and use it to prove that $|\sum_{k \in J}z_k| \geq \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_k|$ for any $J \subset \left \{ 1,2,..n \right \}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I think that what you mean is that there is $J$ for which that holds, as that is definitely not true for all $J$

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I'll edit that. It is for some J

Comment: If you let $f(t)=\sum <z_k,e^{it}>_+$ it follows that $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}f(t)dt =\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_k|$ and this means that there is some $t_0, f(t_0) \ge \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_k|$; collecting in $J$ those $k$ for which $\cos (t_0-\arg z_k)>0$ gives you the result since $f(t_0)=\sum_{k \in J} \Re {(e^{-it_0}z_k)} \le \sum_{k \in J} |z_k|$

Comment: @Conrad wow, thanks, you just saved us, we're a group of 4 working on this thing. Cheers!

Comment: happy to be of help